# How do you change a ROS2 WallTimer period after initialization?

Tags: ros2, c++, ros-humble, timer

Is there a way in ROS2 to use the ROS1 **WallTimer** function `setPeriod`? I'm trying to change the timer's period in runtime in my C++ node. Currently I cancel the existing timer and create a new timer every time I want to change the period which doesn't seem efficient.

```
// Cancel the existing timer
if (timer_) {
    timer_->cancel();
}

// Create a new timer with the updated period
timer_ = create_wall_timer(
    std::chrono::microseconds(static_cast<int>(1.0 / speed_ * 1e6)),
    std::bind(&MyNode::timerCallback, this));

...

rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
```

Ideally would like to use something like this.

```
timer_->reset_period(std::chrono::microseconds(updated_timer_period));
```

#### Reference

- ROS1 WallTimer https://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1WallTimer.html
- ROS2 TimerBase https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/rclcpp/generated/classrclcpp_1_1TimerBase.html#exhale-class-classrclcpp-1-1timerbase
- https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/rclcpp/generated/classrclcpp_1_1WallTimer.html

Comment: Seems like a reasonable potential contribution back to `rclcpp` to add it. Or, you can just reconstruct the timer object.

Comment: [rclcpp::TimerBase Class Reference](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1TimerBase.html#aa533702829b0d07cd5a2305b941983dd)